# Created an image with selected area of a webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

Need to create an image with the selected area, I can able to select an area of a page with a background image and got the page X and Y co-ordinates and length of the selected area.  I need to create an image of the selected area, or capture the selected area and save as image. But when I try with draw image it throws common.js?ocauxu:1912 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'selectElements @ common.js?ocauxu:1912dispatch @ jquery.min.js?v=1.8.2:2h @ jquery.min.js?v=1.8.2:2, need a mechanism to create an image with the data I gave, below is the code I have which I tried in Drupal 7.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="ghost-select"><span></span></div><canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="277" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">');
  $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
    $("#big-ghost").remove();
    $(".ghost-select").addClass("ghost-active");
    $(".ghost-select").css({
        'left': e.pageX,
        'top': e.pageY
    });
    initialW = e.pageX;
    initialH = e.pageY;
    $(document).bind("mouseup", selectElements);
    $(document).bind("mousemove", openSelector);

  });    
});

function selectElements(e) {
    $("#score>span").text('0');
    $(document).unbind("mousemove", openSelector);
    $(document).unbind("mouseup", selectElements);
    //Tried to create an image but not working
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvas.toDataURL();
    var img = document.getElementsByClassName("ghost-select");
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);    
    $(".ghost-select").removeClass("ghost-active");
    $(".ghost-select").width(0).height(0);
}

function openSelector(e) {
    var w = Math.abs(initialW - e.pageX);
    var h = Math.abs(initialH - e.pageY);

    $(".ghost-select").css({
        'width': w,
        'height': h
    });
    if (e.pageX <= initialW && e.pageY >= initialH) {
        $(".ghost-select").css({
            'left': e.pageX
        });
    } else if (e.pageY <= initialH && e.pageX >= initialW) {
        $(".ghost-select").css({
            'top': e.pageY
        });
    } else if (e.pageY < initialH && e.pageX < initialW) {
        $(".ghost-select").css({
            'left': e.pageX,
            "top": e.pageY
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with the code?

Comment: There is no problem with the code but at the method selectElements(e) I will have the selected co-ordinates, with that I need to create an image of the selected area, or capture the selected area and save as image.  But when I try with draw image it throws common.js?ocauxu:1912 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'selectElements @ common.js?ocauxu:1912dispatch @ jquery.min.js?v=1.8.2:2h @ jquery.min.js?v=1.8.2:2

Comment: Please update your question with the formatted information from your comment